# How to define route for new method created in Auth controller

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5.1

I have Created new method called "getVarify" in AuthController.php

I can access this method from browser using

```
"SITE_URL/auth/varify/VARIFICATION_CODE".
```

When I am trying to create URL for  tag using below code in .blade.php file, It gives me error.

```
{{ HTML::link('/auth/varify/'.$newlyCreatedUser->varification_code, 'Click to varify') }}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default in Laravel 5.~, Html and Form are not embedded.

Add the following lines in the require section of composer.json and run

```
composer update "illuminate/html": "5.*"
```

Register the service provider in config/app.php by adding the following value into the providers array:

```
'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider'
```

Register facades by adding these two lines in the aliases array:

```
'Form'=> 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade', 'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade'
```